# Неверно срабатывает std::is_const

Tags: c++, итераторы

У меня имеется задание по которому нужно сделать свой итератор, а потом пройти тест итератора на его работоспособность.
Но у меня возникла проблема с проверкой константного итератора.
Сам итератор выглядит так:

```
class const_iterator
{
public:
    typedef const_iterator self_type;
    typedef const std::pair<Key, mapped_type> value_type;
    typedef const value_type& reference;
    typedef const value_type* pointer;
    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    typedef int difference_type;
    //constructors
        const_iterator()
        {
            curr = nullptr;
            currPair = new value_type;
            printf("111\n");
        }
        const_iterator(Tree_ &n)
        {
            printf("2");
            curr = &n;
            currPair = new value_type;
            *currPair = std::make_pair(curr->key, curr->getValue());
        }
        const_iterator(const self_type& other)
        {
            curr = other.curr;
            currPair = new value_type;
            *currPair = *other.currPair;
        }
        const_iterator(const std::pair<Key, mapped_type>& other)
        {
            curr = other.curr;
            currPair = other.currPair;
        }
    //operators
        //prefix increment
        self_type& operator++() {
            //сравни старое значение и новое
            if (currPair->second != curr->getValue())
                curr->setValue(currPair->second);
            curr = successor(); // point to next node
            if (curr)
                *currPair = std::make_pair(curr->key, curr->getValue());
            return *this;
        }
        // postfix increment (it++)
        self_type operator++(int)
        {
            self_type old = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return old;
        }
        //reference
        const reference operator*() const {
            return *currPair;
        }
        //pointer
        const pointer operator->()
        {
            return currPair;
        }
        // Inequality test operator
        bool operator!=(self_type const & other) const {
            return this->curr != other.curr;
        }
        // Dereference operator 
        bool operator==(self_type const & other) const {
            return this->curr == other.curr;
        }

    operator iterator() const { return iterator(); }
private:
    pointer currPair;
    Tree_* curr;
    //Successor
    Tree_* successor()
    {
        if (curr)
            if (curr->right != 0) {
                curr = curr->right;
                while (curr->left != 0)
                    curr = curr->left;
            }
            else {
                Tree_* y = curr->parent;
                if (y == nullptr)
                    return nullptr;
                while (curr == y->right) {
                    curr = y;
                    y = y->parent;
                    if (y == nullptr)
                        return nullptr;
                }
                if (curr->right != y)
                    curr = y;
            }
            return curr;
    }
};
```

проверка же застревает на моменте

```
using mp_it1 = mp::const_iterator;
mp_it1 tmp1;
static_assert(std::is_const<decltype(*tmp1)>::value, "returned value by dereferencing iterator is not const");
```

Компилятор мне говорит:

> Line Error    C2338   returned value
>   by dereferencing iterator is not const

Не могли бы вы мне подсказать что не так с моим итератором, и как это исправить?

Comment: Итераторы не реализовывал, но логика подсказывает: если это const итератор, то и доступ к дереву у него должен быть по const указателю. Аналогично, mapped_type тоже должен быть const. Поправьте, если ошибся

Comment: Я пробовал перевести древо в конст, но результата не было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два момента:

```
    typedef std::pair<Key, mapped_type> value_type;
    typedef value_type& reference;

    //reference
    reference operator*() const {
      return *currPair;
    }
```

у вас `value_type` не константное выражение, поэтому в таком виде у вас возвращается неконстантная ссылка (во втором методе аналогично, но возвращается неконстантный указатель), потому и срабатывает `static_assert`. По сути, вам бы просто добавить `const` перед типом в этих методах (ниже он добавлен):

```
        //reference
        const // имеем: const std::pair<Key, mapped_type>&
        reference operator*() const {
            return *currPair;
        }
        //pointer
        const // имеем: const std::pair<Key, mapped_type>*
        pointer operator->() const // этот const тоже добавлен - дабы не нарушать семантику 
        {
            // и нафига вы так усложняете?
            //return &(operator*());
            // сделайте просто:
            return currPair;
        }
```

Но [корректнее](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator_traits/) будет оставить типы методов как есть (кроме `const`, добавляющего константности методу получения указателя - он нужен), а синонимы типов для указателя и ссылки объявить с `const`:

```
    typedef const value_type& reference;
    typedef const value_type* pointer;
```

Ну и `successor` лучше приватным сделать.

А ещё, по хорошему, нужно добавть ещё `typedef` для определения категории итератора: `typedef ... iterator_category;` и для `difference_type`, [подробности](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator). Нужно, что бы вот [это](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator_traits/) могло работать с вашим итератором.

UPD: да, проглядел, сама проверка тоже некорректна, см: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const, в примерах - ваш случай последний. Не вдаваясь в подробности, но вам нужно убрать ссылку у типа:

static_assert(std::is_const::type>::value, "returned value by dereferencing iterator is not const");

Если коротко, то `is_const` проверяет константность самого выражения, а не значения на которое оно ссылается или указывает. Наглядно это видно на указателях:

```
const int* ptr0;
int* const ptr1;
const int* const ptr2;
```

*Первый* - это НЕКОНСТАНТНЫЙ указатель (т.е. его значение можно изменить и он будет указывать на другой блок памяти) на КОНСТАНТНЫЕ данные (а вот данные по этому указателю изменить нельзя). Так как значение самого указателя изменить можно, то `is_const` тут вернёт `false`. Хотя по семантике вашего использования это именно то, что вам нужно: запретить менять данные.

*Второй* - это КОНСТАНТНЫЙ указатель на НЕКОНСТАНТНЫЕ данные. Т.е. изменить сам указатель нельзя, только единожды инициализировав, а вот данные по нему - пожалуйста. `is_const` для него - `true`.

*Третий* - это собрали всё вместе: нельзя изменить ни значение указателя ни данные по нему. Естественно `is_const` для него - `true`.

Как разобраться - простое мнемоническое правило: квалификаторы до `*` относятся к данным по указателю, после `*` - к самому указателю. Из этого следует что данные записи идентичны:

```
const int* a;
int const* b;
```

Со ссылками чуточку замороченей. В общем и целом правила выше (мысленно) применимы и к ним, т.к. ссылки это сахар над указателями значение которое нельзя изменить. Т.е. запись:

```
int & const a = b;
```

попросту не имеет смысла, т.к. сделать так, что бы `a` ссылался на другой объект мы попросту не сможем. Поэтому такую запись, если мне не изменяет память, недопустимо использовать. Соответственно, разрешено только управление константностью для хранимых данных:

```
const int& a = c;
int const& b = c;
```

Но `is_const` работает с ссылками в том же стиле, что с указателями, именно поэтому для выражений выше он вернёт `false`, хотя, вроде бы, `const` после `&` и так подразумевается.

Именно поэтому, что бы проверить константность доступа к данным по ссылке или указателю, нужно убрать ссылку или указатель из типа и проверить результирующий тип:

```
std::remove_reference<...>::type;
std::remove_pointer<...>::type;
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/uZzwVp, там же почитайте комментарии с префиксом `HTRD:`

Comment: Все сделал придерживаясь совета,  но к сожалению проверка все же не проходит, может ли это быть траблом компилятора VS2014?

Comment: Нет, проглядел проверку малость. Дополнил ответ.